# Find all functions such that $f'(t) = f(t) + \int_0^1 f(\tau)\,d\tau.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

From Spivak

> Find all functions such that $f'(t) = f(t) + \int_0^1 f(\tau)\,d\tau.$

My approach: differentiate both sides to get $f''(t) = f'(t)$, giving $f'(t) = Ce^t$, implying $f(t) = Ce^t + D$. Plugging this into the diff EQ gives $D=\dfrac{1-e}{2}C$, and indeed $f(t)=Ce^t + \dfrac{1-e}{2}C$ satisfies the equation.

Anyone find any errors in this analysis?

Comment: Are you allowed to assume that $f''$ exists? (It does exist, but this needs a proof).

Comment: @127.0.9.6 I don't think so, come to think of it. How do you know it exists?

Comment: We have $f'(t)=f(t)+ k$, so derivative $f'$ exists and by the same relation derivative of $f'$ also exists.

Comment: same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86250/finding-all-functions-f-satisfying-ft-ft-int-abftdt?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a kind of Fredholm integro-differetial equation. Just as the comment of @127.0.9.6, you can not ensure $f''$ is exist. In other words, we can only claim that $f\in C^1$ or $f\in H^1$.

Assume $\int_0^1f(\tau)d\tau=C$ then the equation can be written as $f'(t)=f(t)+C$. This is a simple 1st order linear ODE. It have a general solution that $f(t)=C_1e^t-C$, which $C_1$ is a constant. Next, integrate each sides of this solution, we have:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1f(t)dt=C_1\int_0^1 e^tdt-C\\
C=C_1(e-1)-C\\
C=\frac{C_1(e-1)}{2}
\end{equation}
So the solution of the equation is $f(t)=C_1e^t-\frac{C_1(e-1)}{2}$. If some initial condition have been given, the constant $C_1$ can be determined.

Our solutions are same but I do not use the 2nd derivative of $f(t)$.

Comment: Fantastic!------

Answer (score 4):

I find the presence of integral puzzling; let's just write for now $f'(t)=f(t)+A$ where $A$ is a constant. Since this is assumed to hold for every $t$, we know that $f$ is differentiable. But then $f'(t)$, being $f(t)+A$, is differentiable too. So, $f$ is twice differentiable.

(This is a very simple example of *bootstrapping*, a way of iteratively improving regularity of solutions. It could be continued to show $f\in C^\infty$, if needed.)

Then your argument goes through as written: $f''(t)=f'(t)$, hence $f'$ is an exponential, and then you figure out the constants. (At the last step, the fact that $A$ is some integral of  $f$ becomes relevant.)